# ip адрес в PostAsync

Tags: c#, httpclient

```
public string url1 = "https://portal.fedsfm.ru:8081/Services/fedsfm-service";
public string url2 = "https://188.254.86.136:8081/Services/fedsfm-service";

await client.PostAsync(url1, httpContent); // Первый запрос
await client.PostAsync(url1, httpContent); // Второй запрос
```

Почему первый запрос работает (возвращает response), а второй нет (возвращает null)? 188.254.86.136 я получил с помощью

```
string howtogeek = "portal.fedsfm.ru";
            IPAddress[] addresslist = 
                Dns.GetHostAddresses(howtogeek);
```

Comment: Уточните в вопросе (изменить вопрос - кнопка [edit]), что именно значит "не работает": если выдаёт ошибку, напишите какую.

Comment: Потому что администратор сайта скорей всего сделал привязку только к домену, а ip адрес игнорирует. Сами попробуйте в браузере открыть `https://portal.fedsfm.ru` и `https://188.254.86.136`.

Comment: Ну, кстати, да. Для вебсайта может быть важно, как вы его открываете, для него обращение по ip и по dns может быть не одно и то же.

Comment: Отмечу еще тот факт, что домен не всегда ведет на реальный адрес сервера, учитывайте это тоже. К примеру CloudFlare скрывает реальный IP сервера и при пинге или вот коде из вопроса вы будете получать сервера CloudFlare, а не сервера данного сайта. Поэтому, получение IP это не лучшая затея и все очень сильно зависит от сервера.

Comment: Потому что url прописан в SSL сертификате, айпишник - нет.